# How to get the numeric value of an entity (displayed in label)?

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to get the numeric value of an entity (to be displayed) on label

```
  lblHrLHSHRDOT.Text = entity.LHXHours + entity.SHOTRDXHours;
```

Comment: What do you mean by this ?Can u provide and example ?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32()` or `Int32.Parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be missing the type casting try this

`lblHrLHSHRDOT.Text = (entity.LHXHours + entity.SHOTRDXHours).ToString()`